# C++ - Access Global Variables Objects

Tags: c++, object, global-variables, shared

I'm building a C++ project and I would like to create a global custom object. I have created a custom class called Material.

rt.h

```
template<typename T>
class Material
{
    public:
    Vec3<T> ka, kd, ks, kr;
    T sp, transparency, reflectivity;
    Material( ) {
        ka = Vec3<T>(0);
        kd = Vec3<T>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        ks = Vec3<T>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        sp = 0.0;
        kr = Vec3<T>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        reflectivity = 0.0;
        transparency = 0.0;
    }
};
```

At the top of my rt.cpp file I have the following.

```
#include <"rt.h">
Material<float> currentMaterial();
```

Later I call currentMaterial and get an error

```
raytracer.cpp:294:3: error: base of member reference is a function; perhaps you meant to call it with no arguments?
            currentMaterial.ka = Vec3<float>(kar, kag, kab);
```

when I call:

```
currentMaterial.ka = Vec3<float>(kar, kag, kab);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Material<float> currentMaterial();
```

looks like a function declaration to the compiler. Declare your variable like this:

```
Material<float> currentMaterial;
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats

`Material<float> currentMaterial();`

as 

`Material<float> currentMaterial(void);`

A function declaration, with a void argument and a Material return type.

So you shoud write 

`Material<float> currentMaterial;`

instead.